# C# remove To if datagridview cell has a specific text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, datagridview

I have a code that will email all that are visible on the datagridview. I want it to delete anyone that is listed as "open position" before placing everyone's name in the email TO section.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the code i have so far....

```
 try
 {
     String str = "", str1 = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
     {
         str1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["C1"].Value.ToString();
         if (!str.Contains(str1)) str += str1 + ";";
         str1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["C2"].Value.ToString();
         if (!str.Contains(str1)) str += str1 + ";";

         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem);  
         outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
         mailItem.To = str;
         mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
         mailItem.Display(false);

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq

```
// get c1 cell values to a list
var c1 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.Cells["C1"].Value.ToString()).ToList();

// get c2 cell values to a list
var c2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.Cells["C2"].Value.ToString()).ToList();

// remove duplicates and join them and assign 
mailItem.To = string.Join(";", c1.Union(c2).ToArray());
```

If you have any other column value which decide selecting of cell value, you can simply add where condition and filter records like below

```
// get c1 cell values to a list
var c1 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r=>r.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString() != "open")
    .Select(row => row.Cells["C1"].Value.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: How would be able to remove anyone on the list that has a name of "open"? Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! One last thing..how would i union more than 2 items, if i wanted C3, C4..? Thank you!!

Comment: Do you know how i can do the same with this code.....mailItem.To = lblc1name.Text + ";" + lblc2name.Text + ";" + lblc3name.Text + ";"
                    + lblc4name.Text;